# How can I prevent a leaky abstraction?

Tags: c#, dependencies, code-injection, abstraction

I'm writing an Active Directory wrapper, trying to follow SOLID and other best practices. The interface is currently "IActiveDirectory".

The problem I have now is that the implementation ActiveDirectory must implement IDisposable to dispose of a few resources that are created and disposed inside this wrapper, and I'm not sure how to address this concern while trying to code to an interface, etc... I don't want to create a leaky abstraction (i.e. decorating IActiveDirectory w/ IDisposable.) I can't make the service granular (i.e. scoping the creation/disposal of resources to method calls) due to the performance of the underlying dependencies.

I currently have a factory so that consumers of IActiveDirectory can create one on-demand, but I need a clean, convenient way for the consumer to signal it is done with the resource.

How can I provide consumers a contract (i.e. an interface) without leaking the abstraction of a resource wrapper? Should I just expose the implementation sans an interface? Is there a way for my consumer or my DI container to manage the lifetime of this service?

Comment: "I need a clean, convenient way for the consumer to signal it is done with the resource." -- that's exactly what `IDisposable` is. You can't abstract over *everything*.

Comment: Yes I'm aware that's exactly what IDisposable is, and I have no problem putting it on a concrete class. I do, however, dislike putting it on an interface because I'm creating a leaky abstraction whereby I assume all implementations need a Dispose method call, violating Liskov. Do you think it would be better to just expose the concrete sans an interface?

Comment: It's perfectly valid, under LSP and under other criteria, for `Dispose` to do nothing. Putting it on an interface doesn't mean assuming all implementations need disposing (any implementation that doesn't can simply add `void Dispose() {}`), it means assuming *some* implementations need disposing (which is true).

Comment: @delnan I still believe it is a violation of Liskov precisely because the interface is bending to the needs of at least one of its concretes, and that it's possible at least one implementation doesn't "need" what the interface calls for. Still, I admit that even if it is a violation, it's not a large problem in practice because the method is void and by convention shouldnt throw/cause exceptions or surprises in any use case.

Comment: @delnan IMO liskov violations should generally be taken seriously as they hint at refactoring towards cleaner/more maintainable code, but I suppose theory and practice can't converge to a solution in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

On one hand, the responsibility to dispose of resource falls on those who acquired it. Your client does not  create ActiveDirectory, the factory does - so conceptually, factory has to dispose of ActiveDirectory.

It's hard, but achievable. One example is web application when you can limit factory scope to that of request, and safely dispose it with active directories when request is done. Another example is when your instance is governed by IoC container which knows how to deal with IDisposable (NInject has some tricky hacks to do just this).

Then, if that does not apply to you, you should admit that generic solution isn't the most performant (which is not surprising at all), and if you still want to be abstract, you may create extra abstraction IActiveDirectorySession which explicitly represents communication session with AD and had to implement IDisposable for very natural reasons, at least.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. I already used the Ambient Context pattern to create a quasi-session by which any objects created under the umbrella of the service are "registered" for disposal when the context's Dispose is called. Using IoC to manage the lifetime is virtually impossible in this instance because I consider it unacceptable to open the "session" long before and close long after it is needed.